# GitHub PR showing no differences, but files are different

Tags: git, github, commit, pull-request

If I have a file that's different in a sub-branch and is different from the same file in the master branch, but supposedly they are synced up with commits. How do I take the updated file and merge it into the master branch?

Using my own repo [csv2cash](https://github.com/u2berggeist/csv2cash), I have a branch called `translations_ignore`. It has an updated `README.md` file in it. I want to merge it into the `master` branch.

If I open a pull request though, it says all the commits are synced. The `master/README.md` and the `translations_ignore/README.md` are quite different though.

I know there's a difference between commit being up to date and files being the same, but I'm still really confused as to what's going on.

Also, if I try to do a PR the reverse way (merge `master` into `translations_ignore`), then it then recognizes the changes in files.

Edit: for future reference, I've tagged the state of the `master` and `transaction_ignore` branches [here](https://github.com/u2berggeist/csv2cash/releases/tag/StackExchangeQ) and [here](https://github.com/u2berggeist/csv2cash/releases/tag/StackExchangeQ2) respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your commit structure looks like the following at the moment:

```
--C----B-----A
       |     |
       |     master
      translations_ignore
```

So all your commits of translations_ignore are already part of the master branch, that's why it doesn't show a difference. If you want to have the state of commit B in master, you can revert commit A (although this will revert all the changes, not only those of the readme file), or you can checkout Readme.md from commit B, while you are on master branch. Then you get the content from commit B and you can create a new commit with your desired state.

```
git checkout translations_ignore - README.md
```

That will checkout the file README.md from the translations_ignore branch.

Comment: Maybe I don't have a good grasp of git then. If all the commits from translations_ignore are in the master branch, then how are the files different?

Comment: You have added commit A on master branch, where you reverted some changes in README.md. That was the commit: https://github.com/u2berggeist/csv2cash/commit/ee2d149a228d1b463dcd35d71f7406af610e737e